# Formatting the date ASP.NET C# for the Edit View

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have the below code to format the date on my views.

```
[DisplayName("Date Last Seen")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? LostDate { get; set; }
```

It all works except that when I click the Edit view the current value of "LostDate" does not get rendered automatically.

How do I fix this?

**Edit**
I have the code below for the edit view.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LostDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LostDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LostDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 2** 
I have resolved the issue of the date not appearing by changing "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" to {0:yyyy-MM-dd} but in all my other views the date now appears in the year first format.

Comment: are you set current date on view right?

Answer (score 0):

Create class constructor and set default value. for example.

```
public Classname()
{
    LostDate=DateTime.Now;
}

public DateTime? LostDate { get; set; }
```

**Other option**

use custom validation. [so refer this link in more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx)

try it.

Comment: Same result. I can get it to appear if I remove the (DataType.Date) but then I loss the dropdown calendar and format.

Comment: so use DataType(DataType.DateTime) and try it

Comment: I still lose the dropdown calendar and when I click away from the field, it states there it is in the wrong format.

Comment: Please change this Line.

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LostDate, new {  @class = "form-control" } )